# Change seed in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, devise, rack, seed

I have a rails projects and when I initially create the seed, the log_in page is authorizing my entry, but if I change the seed file and do

```
bundle exec rake db:reset
```

- which I understood it's compiling even the seed file, I receive a 401 Unauthorized message error.

seeds.rb

```
User.where(email: 'john_doe@yahoo.com').first_or_create! (password:'000111222')
```

Am I modifying the seed in the wrong way? Should I generate anything else, apart from just changing the seed file on the plain text?

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:root, :forgot_password]
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
before_action :update_headers_to_disable_caching
before_action :ie_warning
skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token

## The following are used by our Responder service classes so we can access
## the instance variable for the current resource easily via a standard method
def resource_name
 controller_name.demodulize.singularize
end

def current_resource
  instance_variable_get(:"@#{resource_name}")
end

def current_resource=(val)
  instance_variable_set(:"@#{resource_name}", val)
end

# Catch NotFound exceptions and handle them neatly, when URLs are mistyped or mislinked
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
  render template: 'errors/error_404', status: 404
end
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do
  render template: 'errors/error_403', status: 403
end

# IE over HTTPS will not download if browser caching is off, so allow  browser caching when sending files
def send_file(file, opts={})
  response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'private, proxy-revalidate' # Still prevent proxy caching
  response.headers['Pragma'] = 'cache'
  response.headers['Expires'] = '0'
  super(file, opts)
end

private
  def update_headers_to_disable_caching
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-cache="set-cookie", 
     no-store, private, proxy-revalidate'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
    response.headers['Expires'] = '-1'
  end

  def ie_warning
    return redirect_to(ie_warning_path) if request.user_agent.to_s =~ /MSIE   
    [6-7]/ && request.user_agent.to_s !~ /Trident\/7.0/
  end

  def current_user
    return unless session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

 protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:email, 
    :password, :remember_me) }
  end
 end
```

Comment: I guess `rake db:reset` doesn't runs seed if you are on rails 3/4 (not sure). So did you run `rake db:seed` after the reset?

Comment: Yes, and I get a SQL Unique contraint exception as I already have the seed in my database!

Comment: `.first_or_create! (password:'000111222')` is not the same thing as `.first_or_create!(password:'000111222')`. Putting a space between the method name and parens will cause the contents to be treated as a single argument, not a list of arguments. The result is either a syntax error or really unexpected behaviour.